# Uploading File using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to upload file using jquery ajax instead of direct submitting from form, because I want to send some additional parameter with form data .But I am getting error 403 forbidden , even if I am sending csrf value .I am using spring mvc framework ..

Comment: Code snippet would help us to find out what is wrong in your approach.

Comment: better if you share your code and we can check if there is a problem

Comment: this problem You do not have the right to access,I think spring security prevents this requests ,sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        // Submit form data via Ajax
        $("#fupForm").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submit.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('#fupForm').css("opacity",".5");
                },
                success: function(response){ //console.log(response);
                    $('.statusMsg').html('');
                    if(response.status == 1){
                        $('#fupForm')[0].reset();
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<p class="alert alert-success">'+response.message+'</p>');
                    }else{
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">'+response.message+'</p>');
                    }
                    $('#fupForm').css("opacity","");
                    $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```